# Issue with SCM Stats plugin on Sonar dry run analysis

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using Sonar eclipse plugin version 3.1.1.20130521-1304-RELEASE.

When I run a local analysis from the plugin the console looks like

```
INFO: Sonar Server 3.5.1
17:15:41.103 INFO  - Load batch settings
17:15:41.617 INFO  - User cache: 
17:15:41.630 INFO  - Install plugins
17:15:41.854 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, pdfreport, views, report, scmactivity
17:15:47.571 INFO  - -------------  Executing Project Scan
17:15:49.494 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
17:15:49.494 INFO  - Dry run
17:15:53.028 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for 
17:15:54.094 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
17:15:59.013 INFO  - -------------  Inspecting DPortal
17:15:59.045 INFO  - Load module settings
17:16:00.721 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=,language=java]
17:16:00.819 INFO  - Excluded tests: 
17:16:00.820 INFO  -   **/package-info.java
17:16:00.911 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
17:16:01.077 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2013-06-03)
17:16:01.135 INFO  - Compare over 5 days (2013-05-29, analysis of 2013-06-03 04:32:51.903)
17:16:01.168 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2013-05-04, analysis of 2013-06-03 04:32:51.903)
17:16:02.333 INFO  - Base dir: 
17:16:02.333 INFO  - Working dir: 
17:16:02.333 INFO  - Source dirs: 
17:16:02.334 INFO  - Test dirs: 
17:16:02.338 INFO  - Binary dirs: 
17:16:02.338 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_US
17:19:58.735 WARN  - SCM URL must not be blank. SCM Stats Plugin will not run.Please check the parameter SCM URL or the <scm> section of Maven pom.
```

I'm not sure why it waits for 3 minutes in that line.

Also It'd be great if I can run local analysis on specific src dirs (which are sub-modules from maven POMs) instead of the whole project. Is there already a way I can do this?

**UPDATE:**
I'm only interested in the violations. Can I force local analysis to skip others plugins?

**UPDATE 2:**
I tried setting the local analysis properties mentioned by @fabrice in the eclipse workspace settings.

[image: Workspace Local Analysis properties]

But it seems to be picking up only a few properties from the Sonar console log below.
Others like sonar.importSources it just ignores?
Also it does not seem to respect the project specific property sonar.includeModules set as a single module. It still uses all the src directories.

```
INFO: Sonar Server 3.5.1
13:16:35.022 INFO  - Load batch settings
13:16:35.413 INFO  - User cache: 
13:16:35.421 INFO  - Install plugins
13:16:35.653 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, pdfreport, views, report, buildstability, scmactivity, buildbreaker
13:17:50.854 INFO  - -------------  Executing Project Scan
13:17:51.908 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
13:17:51.924 INFO  - Dry run
13:17:54.506 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:
13:17:55.342 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
13:17:59.932 INFO  - -------------  Inspecting DPortal
13:17:59.938 INFO  - Load module settings
13:18:03.169 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=Dportal Alert Thresholds,language=java]
13:18:03.173 INFO  - Excluded tests: 
13:18:03.174 INFO  -   **/package-info.java
13:18:03.251 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
13:18:03.397 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2013-06-04)
13:18:03.447 INFO  - Compare over 5 days (2013-05-31, analysis of 2013-06-04 12:57:34.79)
13:18:03.498 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2013-05-06, analysis of 2013-06-04 12:57:34.79)
13:18:07.592 INFO  - Base dir: 
13:18:07.592 INFO  - Working dir: 
13:18:07.593 INFO  - Source dirs: 
13:18:07.595 INFO  - Test dirs: 
13:18:07.601 INFO  - Binary dirs: 
13:18:07.602 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
13:22:13.356 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
13:23:35.056 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 81700 ms
13:23:35.057 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
13:24:53.888 INFO  - Java AST scan...
13:28:08.900 INFO  - Java AST scan done: 195012 ms
13:28:10.152 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 275095 ms
13:28:10.152 INFO  - Sensor FindbugsSensor...
13:28:10.152 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 2.0.1...
13:28:42.363 INFO  - Findbugs output report:
```

Answer (score 2):

The new version of the Eclipse Sonar plugin is:  3.2.0.20130627-1142-RELEASE

We had a similar issue. The default list did not cover enough.
Here is value we used (it disables all SCM plugins):

- Name: sonar.dryRun.excluded
- Value: devcockpit,jira,pdfreport,views,report,scmactivity,scmstats

Note:

1. This is just the default list with the "scmstats" added to the end.
2. The list must not contain any extra spaces between the comma and the plugin name.
3. I am unsure of where to find all plugin names, but I imagine the Sonar Administrator can determine the plugin names.

It would be nice if the console output or the Sonar Settings screen reported the sonar plugin name for general users, since we are the ones running the Local Analysis...

Answer (score 1):

1. Looks like you've got an issue with the SCM Stats Plugin. Remove it and this should work perfectly. (everything may seem OK on the server side, but this doesn't mean at all that the plugin will execute without any error on the batch side)
2. If you want to run the analysis only on some sub-modules, then you should use the "sonar.skippedModules" property. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters
3. To include/exclude plugin from dryRun analyses, you can use the following properties (comma separated list of plugin keys):

   - sonar.dryRun.includePlugins
   - sonar.dryRun.excludePlugins

Comment: But it works fine at the server, is there a provision to disable plugins selectively from the eclipse plugin for local analysis alone?

Comment: Also please have look at the Update in the end of the question.

Comment: Updated the question again.